# Using an existent Postgres-DB with tables in Node.js with Sequelize (ORM)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, mean-stack

I'm pretty newbie in Node.js and Postgres, my question is very simple:

It is possible syncing an existent Postgres-DB, which have tables (and data), using Sequelize, without re-writing the models and relations?

How are the CRUD basic operations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sequelize-Auto](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) can help you with that.